# Get automated names for JS object keys

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm building a JS script in GoogleEarthEngine. I am automating the code for many year to get a vegetation index (Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI)) for each year. The code I'm working itself is much more complex, that's why I just added one here for this question.([code here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ba34dae7aa86a40d0bd19eedc7d00cc7)).

I'm trying to get the name of the layer in the **key** of the JS Object. So it would be:

```
buffer_size: 500
class: 0
EVI_2021_mean: MEAN_VALUE_FOR_THIS_YEAR
```

and have in the end, other columns following the same idea, only changing the year value in the **Key** of the object and its mean value for the **Value** of the object

The format itself is important to be that way so I can export to KML it afterwards and move on with further analysis.

Instead, what I'm getting is the string *'key'* as the **Key** and the string *EVI_2021_mean* as the **Value**.

```
features: List (4 elements)
0: Feature 0 (Polygon, 3 properties)
type: Feature
id: 1
geometry: Polygon, 24 vertices
properties: Object (3 properties)
    buffer_size: 500
    class: 0
    key: EVI_2021_mean
```

Obs: I'm setting the mean value inside the GetMean function:

```
var GetMean = function (fc, img, nome_img) {
  print(nome_img);
  
  var dict = [];
  var ZS_mean =  img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
    ,geometry: POI
    ,scale: 30
  });
  dict.push({
    key:   nome_img+'_'+'mean',
    value: ZS_mean.constant
  });
  print(ZS_mean);

  var SetMean = function(f) {
    return f.set(dict[0]);
  };
  
  return POI.map(SetMean);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set dynamic keys for JavaScript objects using the following notation:

```js
const myKey = 'someKey'
const myObj = {
    [myKey]: 'myValue'
}

console.log(myObj)  // => { someKey: 'myValue' }
```

Additionally, you can set a dynamic property on an existing object like so:

```js
const myKey = 'someKey'
const myObj = {}

myObj[myKey] = 'myValue'

console.log(myObj)  // => { someKey: 'myValue' }
```

I'd suggest modifying your code to make `dict` an object (like `dict = {}`) and where you `dict.push({ ... })` to do like `dict[nome_img+'_mean'] = ZS_mean.constant`.